# Efficiant way to check large number string existing in database

Tags: java, php, sql, database, logic

I have a very large table in the database, the table has a column called
"unique_code_string", this table has almost 100,000,000 records.

Every 2 minutes, I will receive 100,000 code string, they are in an array and they are unique to each other. I need to insert them to the large table if they are all "good".
The meaning of "good" is this:
All 100,000 codes in the array never occur in the database large table.

If one or more codes occur in the database large table, the whole array will not use at all, 
it means no codes in the array will insert into the large table.

Currently, I use this way:
First I do a loop and check each code in the array to see if there is already same code in the database large table.
Second, if all code is "new", then, I do the real insert.
But this way is very slow, I must finish all thing within 2 minutes.

I am thinking of other ways:

1. Join the 100,000 code in a SQL "in clause", each code has 32 length, I think no database will accept this 32*100,000 length "in clause".
2. Use database transaction, I force insert the codes anyway, if error happens, the transaction rollback. This cause some performance issue.
3. Use database temporary table, I am not good at writing SQL querys, please give me some example if this idea may work.

Now, can any experts give me some advice or some solutions?

I am a non-English speaker, I hope you see the issue I am meeting.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you use SQL's Insert Ignore? 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/

Comment: Instinct would say that option 2. would be the right way to go about this. _“Performance issues”_ might arise when dealing with such an amount of data, yes, but I doubt any other ways would improve that significantly. I don’t see how a temporary table would help here at all, plus with that amount of data it would probably still mean that stuff gets written to disk anyway.

Comment: @J_C I cannot use that, because if any codes already exists in database table, then  that entire array(100,000 codes) will not use at all. Still thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the 100,000 rows into a table!

Create a unique index on the original table:

```
create unique index unq_bigtable_uniquecodestring on bigtable (unique_code_string);
```

Now, you have the tools you need.  I think I would go for a transaction, something like this:

```
insert into bigtable ( . . . )
    select . . . 
    from smalltable;
```

If any row fails (due to the unique index), then the transaction will fail and nothing is inserted.  You can also be explicit:

```
insert into bigtable ( . . . )
    select . . . 
    from smalltable
    where not exists (select 1
                      from smalltable st join
                           bigtable bt
                           on st.unique_code_string = bt.unique_code_string
                      );
```

For this version, you should also have an index/unique constraint on `smalltable(unique_code_string)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find an optimal solution with so little information. Often this depends on the network latency between application and database server and hardware resources.

1. You can load the 100,000,000 `unique_code_string` from the database and use `HashSet` or `TreeSet` to de-duplicate in-memory before inserting into the database. If your database server is resource constrained or there is considerable network latency this might be faster.
2. Depending how your receive the 100,000 records delta you could load it into the database e.g. a CSV file can be read using [external table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm). If you can get the data efficiently into a temporary table and database server is not overloaded you can do it very efficiently with SQL or stored procedure.

You should spend some time to understand how real-time the update has to be e.g. how many SQL queries are reading the 100,000,000 row table and can you allow some of these SQL queries to be cancelled or blocked while you update the rows. Often it's a good idea to create a shadow table:

- Create new table as copy of the existing 100,000,000 rows table.
- Disable the indexes on the new table
- Load the delta rows to the new table
- Rebuild the indexes on new table
- Delete the existing table
- Rename the new table to the existing 100,000,000 rows table

The approach here is database specific. It will depend on how your database is defining the indexes e.g. if you have a [partitioned table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm) it might be not necessary.

Comment: I used this method before, I loaded 100,000,000 to a big Java Set, as them from the database bigtable, they already unique! But I still cannot escape 100,000 loop to check each new codes existing in that BigJavaSet.`for(100,000 times) loop check BigJavaSet contains each code`. Every check is string compare, and 100,000 times take too much time. The worse thing is: before I check all 100,000 codes, I can do nothing else.

Comment: You can further improve this by using multiple threads to compare in parallel. One way or another you always have to perform 100,000 comparisons if these are random strings, even when you load it into the database the SQL engine will do it.